# retrieve std out redirect to /dev/null

Tags: process, io-redirection, stdout

is there a way to retrieve std out redirected to /dev/null?
I tried `tail -f /proc/{PID}/fd/1`, looks like only works except redirects to `/dev/null`.

i.e.

`tail -f /proc/${cmd_pid}/fd/1`

works on `cmd > log.txt` but not `cmd > /dev/null`

------------update------------

in fact, my problem is `log.txt` will be quite large if always log the stdout. it will be best if i could control when to log or stop the log (without stopping the `cmd` process itself).

so if is possible to redirect the stdout to some `tmp` filesystem that occupies no resouce, and when i need i can retrieve the stdout?

Comment: If it occupies no resource, where do you imagine you'll be retrieving data from?

Comment: `/proc/$PID/fd/$N` is only a link to what ever file-like object the fd in question is connected to it, nothing else. If it's a file, you can use that to open the file. If it's `/dev/null`, you can use that to open `/dev/null`, though it still contains no data.

Comment: "it will be best if i could control when to log or stop the log" – See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445932/108618).

Comment: `no resource` is indeed ambiguity, or `minimal resource` is more precise...e.g., when i'm not retrieving it, the stdout could be discarded, when i start to retrieve, then the stdout could redirected to a log file.

Comment: Related: [Store output of a command into a ring-buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148291)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `cmd > /dev/null`, the shell, in a new child process, opens fd 1 onto `/dev/null` and executes `cmd`.

`cmd` does some `write(1, "output"...)` to write data to stdout (or possibly other writing system calls such as `send`, `sendmsg` or `pwrite`) regardless of what that fd is open on.

On Linux, `/proc/$pid_of_cmd/fd/1` will just be a magic symlink to `/dev/null`, the file fd 1 is open on, so `tail -f that` will just be the same as `tail -f /dev/null`.

You could intercept those `write()` system calls with `strace` and decode the result:

```
strace -zqqs99999 -xxa0 -o /dev/stdout -e write -p "$pid" |
   perl -ne 'print chr(hex($_)) for /\\x(..)/g'
```

Or:

```
strace -zqqs99999 -xxa0 -o /dev/stdout -e write -p "$pid" |
   perl -ne 'if (/^write\(1,/) {print chr(hex($_)) for /\\x(..)/g}'
```

For only the `write()`s to stdout (fd 1). Or:

```
strace -yzqqs99999 -xxa0 -o /dev/stdout -e write -p "$pid" |
   perl -ne 'if (/^\Qwrite(1<\x2f\x64\x65\x76\x2f\x6e\x75\x6c\x6c>,\E "(.*)"/) {
     print chr(hex($_)) for $1 =~ /\\x(..)/g}'
```

For only the `write()`s to stdout (fd 1) and only when stdout is open on `/dev/null`.

Note that if you redirect the output of `perl` to something other than a tty device, it will start buffering by blocks instead of by line, so you'll only see the output in batches of a few kibibytes. You can disable that buffering by setting the `$|` variable to `1`:

```
strace -zqqs99999 -xxa0 -o /dev/stdout -e write -p "$pid" |
   perl -ne 'BEGIN{$| = 1}
             print chr(hex($_)) for /\\x(..)/g' > file
```

---

Alternatively, instead of doing `cmd > /dev/null`, do `cmd | cat > /dev/null`.

Then `cmd`'s stdout will be a pipe, and on Linux, `/proc/$pid_of_cmd/fd/1` will behave like a named pipe, so if you do:

```
kill -s STOP "$pid_of_cat"
cat "/proc/$pid_of_cmd/fd/1"
```

You will actually redirect the pipe to your new `cat` command.

If you terminate that new `cat`, you'll want to resume the other one (`kill -s CONT "$pid_of_cat"`) to reopen the tap to `/dev/null` on that pipe.

To actually change where stdout of the process goes, you could attach a debugger:

```
gdb --pid "$pid_of_cmd"
```

Then in gdb:

```
call close(1)
p open("/path/to/some/file", 0x241, 0600)
detach
```

(0x241 for O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT)

Check that `open()` returns fd 1. If not, you may need some call to `dup2()` and an extra `close()`.

Comment: `strace -zqqs99999 -xxa0 -o /dev/stdout -e write -p "$pid" |
   perl -ne 'print chr(hex($_)) for /\\x(..)/g'` works, but only works on terminal output, how can i redirect this to some log file? i tried `(strace -zqqs99999 -xxa0 -o /dev/stdout -e write -p "$pid" |
   perl -ne 'print chr(hex($_)) for /\\x(..)/g') >> t.log` but no works

Comment: @furynerd, you're probably seeing the effect of buffering, it's not that it doesn't work, it's that the output then comes in large blocks. See edit for how to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the file handle.

> so if is possible to redirect the stdout to some tmp filesystem that occupies no resouce, and when i need i can retrieve the stdout?

No, you can't store the data without storing it *somewhere*.

Someone has probably written a cirular buffer - which would allow you to see (say) the last 100k of data. Alternatively if the program is normally running headless you could send the output to the screen and run it via `screen`.

Answer (score 0):

> when i'm not retrieving it, the stdout could be discarded, when i start to retrieve, then the stdout could redirected to a log file.

This could be done by piping the output to a shell script, like the following:

```bash
#! /bin/sh
# a-script.sh
while IFS= read -d input
do
  printf "%s\n" input >> /some/file
done
```

Note that the redirection is done inside the loop, specifically so that the output file is opened anew in each iteration. Then, to start:

```
ln -s /dev/null /some/file
cmd | a-script.sh
```

Then when you want the logs:

```
ln -sf /some/log/file /some/file
```

And the next iteration of the loop will start writing to `/some/log/file` instead of to `/dev/null`.

If your command logs heavily, this could place a severe performance penalty.